# Accessing a dict in Python results in TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
step = 0
batch_size = 128
iters = 2618730
while step * batch_size < iters:
    batch_x = train_data[(step * batch_size):((step+1) * batch_size)]
    batch_y = labels[(step * batch_size):((step+1) * batch_size)]
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y keep_prob: dropout})
```

In the above snippet I'm trying to access train_data which is of 133 x 229498 (in dict form) in batches of 128, but it is throwing the following error

```
batch_x = train_data[(step * size):((step+1) * size)]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: `train_data` is a *dictionary*. You can not slice a dictionary.

Comment: How exactly did you "load" `train_data`?

Comment: What are the keys of the dictionary? Or, what is the structure of your dictionary? Slicing doesn't work on dictionaries

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have loaded the train_data via pickle, so the train_data is in dictionary form

Comment: @NChauhan I have a 133 x 229498 feature vector which I have loaded from a pickle file so now the train_data is in dictionary form, so would slicing work on 2D array if I convert the dict to 2D??

Comment: @SumRchn: how would you convert a dictionary to an array?